# Relation between height and depth of not complete binary tree

Tags: algorithm, heap

"Let H be the height of the tree. If the heap is not a complete
binary tree (because the bottom level is not full), then the
nodes at a given depth don’t all have the same height. Eg.,
although all the nodes with depth H have height 0, the nodes
with depth H-1 may have either height 0 or 1"

Found this explanation when searching for the explanation of statement --**"max node with given height h in N-element heap = **N/2^(h+1)**"** as per CLRS.

Does this means that different level (different depth) node can have same height?

I know that no. of leaves in a heap is N/2, does this somehow related???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, this is a valid heap:

```
        __1__
       /     \
      3       5
     / \     / \
    4   9   6   10
   / \
  7   11
```

Now compare the situation of node 5 and node 4. They are at a different level (i.e. at a different depth), but have the same height (i.e., the subtrees that they root have the same height).

On the other hand, we have node 3 and 5 that are on the same level, but they have a different height.

A note about terminology. The quote has *"If the heap is not a complete binary tree..."*. Other sources will define the above example as a "complete binary tree", while a tree that has all its leaves at the bottom level would be called a "perfect binary tree". So I would read that quote as *"If the heap is not a perfect binary tree..."*. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees):

> Some authors use the term *complete* to refer instead to a *perfect* binary tree as defined above

This is obviously confusing and means we always need to verify what an author means with these terms.